# How do I find websockets and websocket urls on a particular website?

Tags: sockets, websocket

I have been reading about websocket connections and using them to collect data at high speeds. I believe I can read the documentation and implement some sort of a websocket connection using python. 
My problem arises in how I would actually go about finding a websocket url (in google chrome developer console for example).
For example on this website: https://www.btc-exchange.com

I know from another stackoverflow post that this website updates the btc prices using a websocket url, but I have no idea how to actually find that url.
An additional question, is once I see the list of websockets that the URL is using - is there any way to identify what each socket is doing? As in, what information is the websocket providing to the website?

I have tried finding it using the chrome developer tools. Perhaps I am just missing an option somewhere, but I can't seem to find what I need.

Just hoping to find a list of websockets that a site is using, and maybe somehow see what data each websocket is providing to the URL.

Thank you!

Comment: There is no discovery mechanism for Websockets.

Comment: Well I ended up being able to find the websocket in the network settings. By just clicking to show WS inside chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much searching I found the solution to my issue inside the network settings of google chrome. 
Instead of clicking all, just click WS (websockets).
Then refresh the page, and if the website is using websockets for streaming data you should see the websocket urls listed right there!
Fairly simple.